# Help -> Asking is out of date

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, stack-overflow, help-center

https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic in the help center needs to be updated with the new close reasons.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not a list of close reasons.  It never was, nor has it ever intended to be, a list of close reasons.  All of the information on that page is still accurately describing what is on topic on this site.

Comment: That's a good point. However, it was structured based directly off of the old close reasons (it may not be a list now but it certainly seems like it used to be). It makes sense that nothing should be removed, but do you think that perhaps *unclear what you're asking* should be added, to maintain a consistent parallel with the close reasons?

Comment: @JasonC As I said before, it was *never* a list of close reasons.  Even in the past, it did not coincide with the close reasons.  There is overlap, sure, a fair bit, but there is no intent for them to be the same.  A post being "clear" isn't related to it being "on topic".  It doesn't belong in that list.  A post can be unclear and still be on topic.  The same reasoning applies to "too broad" and "primarily opinion based".  None of those three reasons are there.

Comment: When somebody posts a question that is primarily opinion based, then says, "Sorry I posted this; why is this a problem and what kinds of questions *are* on topic here?" help/on-topic is not a sufficient answer to that question in that context. Where should I send them?

Comment: @JasonC http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask

Comment: probably want to link to the non-meta version of it, but yeah.